# Probabilities/Poisson distribution exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm new to this site and I'm having trouble while solving a probability problem.
The question is: We have a regional airport, and the number of planes that arrive on the airport follow a poisson distribution of y=2
What is the probability of at least 3 planes takeoff in at least 3 of 5 days?

I was thinking about hipergeometrical probability, but I really have no idea how to solve this. I'd apreciate a lot if someone could give me a hand on this.

EDIT: The answer is 0,195

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that at least 3 planes take off during day 1?

Comment: @Did: Ok, I still don't get it. I calculate your hint(aprox 0.323). What do I have to do now? Shouldn't it be p(3days)+p(4days)+p(5days)?

Comment: Next step: call a day "successful" if at least 3 planes take off during that day. So, day 1 has probability p to be successful (and you say that p = 0.323). Can you show that each day has the same probability of being successful, independently of the others? What does that tell you about the number of successful days amongst days 1 to 5?

Comment: OP: You just threw away an occasion to think by yourself. Your call. By the way, why use a binomial in the last step of the accepted answer? If I were your TA, I would focus on the justifications of that.

Comment: OP: Still in the perspective of handing back this homework, you might be interested to know that the paragraph in the accepted answer discussing the average of a Poisson random variable is wrong. Once again, your call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have

Poisson$(\lambda,k)$

$$p(X=k)={\lambda^k\over k!}e^{-\lambda}.$$

The Poisson part tells us via the measurement for one unit of time, that $y=2$.The average of a poisson is $1\over\lambda$, so it's not clear to me whether $\lambda=2$ or ${1\over2}$. Is 2 the average number of planes, or is 2 the decay rate of the distribution? Let's assume there's 2 planes a day so $\lambda={1\over2}$.

Above, it looks like you found $P(k\ge3\text{ planes in one day})$. (It's easier to calculate the complement?)

Let's notate that with a $p$ for success. Then P(at least 3 days)=P(3)+P(4)+P(5) as you say. And

$$P(k)={5\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k}.$$

Comment: -1. The paragraph on the average of a Poisson random variable is wrong and an explanation of the binomial is lacking.

Comment: you're being spiteful. 11 hours later, everybody's gone home, and you're griping about it. your criticism is not constructive, you fail to offer any specifics.

Comment: What is going on with all the name calling? Not specific? You must be kidding. Why "11 hours later" implies to let a wrong answer as it is? This is contrary to the explicit goal of the site. All these are at best distracting: please address the facts (modifying one's answer is a possibility, you know).

Comment: (You might want to delete your 09:02:36 comment as well, then to address the mathematical facts.)